# Combinar dos arrays y convertirlos en array asociativo

Tags: php, array

Tengo el **array**: `$frutas = ["Naranja", "Manzana", "Pera", "Sandia", "Banana"];`

Y tengo este otro **array**: `$valorPagado = ["Pera" => 10000, "Manzana" => 120000, "Sandia" => 35000];`

Deseo crear un array con los elementos del primer array (**$frutas**) pero con los valores de los precios de cada fruta del segundo array, y si no existe la fruta en el segundo array (**$valorPagado**), pues su valor sería 0, de tal manera que quedara así:

```
$resultado = ["Naranja" => 0, "Manzana" => 120000, "Pera" => 10000, "Sandia" => 35000, "Banana" => 0]
```

Intenté haciendo un `for` al array **$valorPagado**, y validando si en la posición `$i` es igual al del array **$frutas**, entonces que asignara el valor, pero no supe hacerlo la manera correcta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de realizarlo es recorriendo el **primer arreglo** y verificando si ya existe el índice en el otro arreglo con `array_key_exists()` de la siguiente manera:

```
$frutas      = ["Naranja", "Manzana", "Pera", "Sandia", "Banana"];
$valorPagado = ["Pera" => 10000, "Manzana" => 120000, "Sandia" => 35000];
foreach ($frutas as $f) {
    if(!array_key_exists($f,$valorPagado)){
        $valorPagado[$f] = 0;
    }
}
var_dump($valorPagado);
```

Básicamente si no existe el índice en el arreglo final entonces lo agregas con valor = 0.

Esto te imprimirá:

```
array(5) { ["Pera"]=> int(10000) ["Manzana"]=> int(120000) ["Sandia"]=> int(35000) ["Naranja"]=> int(0) ["Banana"]=> int(0) }
```